# ImportError: cannot import name 'HDF5Matrix' from 'tensorflow.keras.utils'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model, hdf5, h5py

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-a326ee379f32> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import h5py
----> 2 from tensorflow.keras.utils import HDF5Matrix
      3 _h5_path = '/content/data.h5'
      4 raw_h5 = False
      5 strip_xy = True

ImportError: cannot import name 'HDF5Matrix' from 'tensorflow.keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/api/_v2/keras/utils/__init__.py)
```

> `import h5py
> from tensorflow.keras.utils import HDF5Matrix
> _h5_path = '/content/data.h5'
> raw_h5 = False
> strip_xy = True
> if raw_h5:
> _bare_h5 = h5py.File(_h5_path, 'r')
> def load_xya(in_id):
> in_group = _bare_h5[in_id]
> feat = in_group['feature']
> labels = in_group['label']
> adj = in_group['adjacency_distance']
> return feat, labels, adj
> else:
> def load_xya(in_id, normalize=False):
> use the hdf5matrix wrapper
> feat = HDF5Matrix(_h5_path, f"{in_id}/feature")
> labels = HDF5Matrix(_h5_path, f"{in_id}/label")
> adj = HDF5Matrix(_h5_path, f"{in_id}/adjacency_distance", normalizer=normalized_laplacian if normalize else None)
> return feat, labels, adj
>
> x_train, y_train, adj_train = load_xya('train')
> x_valid, y_valid, adj_valid = load_xya('val')
> x_test, y_test, adj_test = load_xya('test')`

Comment: I guess that was removed after Keras 2.3.0

Comment: Any other idea to import HDF5Matrix?

Comment: Downgrading is only solution in this case. It simply does not exist, was deprecated and deleted.https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/67548eff5989de2b0255f2af75a07f8b9d4ea12c#diff-9ebbebef4127d3b3f14576e55ad6ee93d5b8a97ff67132f7e7c1c73004cd460d

Comment: Hi @SwDL, You can install `h5py` api and can import the `hdf5` file using `f = h5py.File('./train.hdf5', 'r')`. Please have a look at this [link](https://github.com/christianversloot/machine-learning-articles/blob/main/how-to-use-hdf5matrix-with-keras.md#training-a-keras-model-with-hdf5matrix) for your reference.